# Validate Input form in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to validate my form before inserting into database with this code, but I keeps printin ***'You missed a value***'. I would like your help to figure out the problem.

Thanks

```
<?php
 $username   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $pword      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwd']);
 $fname      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
 $lname      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
 $email      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $telephone  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);
 $ad1        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ad1']);
 $ad2        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['street']);
 $ad3        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['town']);
 $pcode      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pcode']);


 if( $username == " " || $pword == " " || $fname == " " || $lname == " " || $email == " ")

    echo 'You missed a value';  
    exit();

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

  mysql_select_db("people", $con);

//$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[description]);
    $pword = md5($pword);
    $sql="INSERT INTO members (username, pword, fname, lname, email, telephone, ad1, ad2, ad3, pcode)
VALUES
('$username','$pword','$fname', '$lname', '$email','$telephone','$ad1','$ad2','$ad3','$pcode')";


  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo "1 record added";

 mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Are assigning values (`=`), not comparing them (`==`). And I think you want to compare against the empty string `""` and against a space `" "`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$username == " "` :) ? P.S: I used to often make the mistake too.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. This time, it inserts data even with some values missing :(

Comment: @Julie - what values are missing?

Comment: @Daniel - If I did not supply all the values in the form page, the code above is allowing me to insert into the database despite the validation code above. I want to make sure that all the vaues are supplied. For example, if I don't supply 'name' in the form, it still allows me to insert.

Comment: @Julie - make sure you have each value in your condition then.

Comment: @Julie - You are missing your `{}` around your if statement (2 lines: `echo` and `exit()`) (single line `if` don't require them, but its good practice to add them all the time) (unless its a typo). 

It might also be easier to check if all the values are not empty (ie `$username != ''`) and if its good, process the data, otherwise print an error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( $username == '' || $pword == '' || $fname == '' || $lname == '' || $email == '')
```

You are assigning an empty space to the variables by doing `$var = ""`, instead of comparing with with the comparison operators `$var == ''`, or stricter `$var === ''`.

---

This would be a little bit cleaner code to follow and maintain:

```
function sqlEscape($string){
    return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($string)."'";
}

if(     $_POST['username']  == '' 
    ||  $_POST['passwd']    == ''
    ||  $_POST['firstname'] == '' 
    ||  $_POST['lastname']  == ''
    ||  $_POST['email']     == '')
{ 
    exit('You missed a value');
}

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('people', $con);

//$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[description]);
$pword = md5($_POST['passwd']);
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO members (username, pword, fname, lname, email, telephone, ad1, ad2, ad3, pcode) 
                VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', 
                sqlEscape($_POST['username']),
                sqlEscape($pword),
                sqlEscape($_POST['firstname']),
                sqlEscape($_POST['lastname']),
                sqlEscape($_POST['email']),
                sqlEscape($_POST['telephone']),
                sqlEscape($_POST['ad1']),
                sqlEscape($_POST['street']),
                sqlEscape($_POST['town']),
                sqlEscape($_POST['pcode']));

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo '1 record added';

mysql_close($con)
```

I added in a function (`sqlEscape`) to run all the `mysql_real_escape_string`, just to make the escapes a piece of cake. Notice that I am calling this function after the MySQL connection has been established, because `mysql_real_escape_string` will NOT work without a connection.

Comment: @Julie: Glad I helped. If your issue is resolved, feel free to accept an answer.

Comment: -Great stuff. I didn't even change anything...worked like charm. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

You should validate off the raw POST values, not the `mysql_real_escape_string` ones. Also you are comparing to  (space) not empty string and assigning them not comparing them.

Comment: @Julie - if i wasn't clear - do it before you call `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: No idea about -1. Your answer actually goes the extra step of fixing some flaws. "Haters gonna hate" I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

check your if condition use **==** instant of **=**

wrong
    if( $username = " " || $pword = " " || $fname = " " || $lname = " " || $email = " ")

Answer (score 2):

Use == instead of = in your if's.

```
if( $username == " " || $pword == " " || $fname == " " || $lname == " " || $email == " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

take out the spaces in this line and you need double equals

```
if( $username = " " || $pword = " " || $fname = " " || $lname = " " || $email = " ")
```

**change to**

```
if( $username == "" || $pword == "" || $fname == "" || $lname == "" || $email == "")
```

Answer (score 2):

`if( $username = " ")` does not compare but assign, use `if( $username == " ")` instead – which still checks, whether the input is a single space-char, which maybe mostly isn't. To check if a variable has content or not use `if(empty($username))`.

Also its maybe better for you to use array_map on the $_POST-array to escape the values:

```
array_map(function($value) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}, $_POST);
```

(If you're prior to PHP 5.3, you need to use a separate function declaration instead of an [anonymous callback](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).)

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, the sign "=" is to set a variable, the comparaison sign is "==" or "===" in PHP.

btw, to minimize your code you can use "array_map" to apply "mysql_real_escape_string" function to your POST array :

`$post = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST);`

Answer (score 1):

`=` is assignment operator. It gives a value.
`==` is comparison operator. It compares the 2 things.
`===` is also a comparison operator, but it compares whether the values and the variable types are the same. You need to remember that.

Also, you can also make your code clearer like this (it's just an example, don't copy paste it because it can be improved and it's not exactly safe):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $columns[] = $key;
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $values[] = "'" . $value ."'";

    if(empty($value))
    {
        $errors[] = 'POST with key '. $key .' was not filled in';
    }
}

if(!isset($errors))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO (". implode(',', $columns .") VALUES (". implode(',', $values .")";

}
else
{
    echo implode('<br />', $errors);
}
```

While learning how to program, if you find yourself copypasting certain code - you then know it's something you can code more intelligently.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $username == " " || $pword == " " || $fname == " " || $lname == " " || $email == " ")
{
 echo 'You missed a value';  
 exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this line after assigning your variables:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== 'POST'){if( $username == " " || $pword == " " || $fname == " " || $lname == " " || $email == " ")

echo 'You missed a value';  
exit();
}
```

//OTHER CODE